# iPhone Dev - Create UIButton Manually

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton

I'm learning how to develop on the iPhone, I bought a book called Beginning iPhone 3 development Exploring the SDK. After I bit I decided to ditch Interface Builder. I still design all my views in IB, but I write It all in code and only use the nib file to get the controls' frames.

So now I need to make a `UIButton`, and the documentation is different from the other controls. I tried using `initWithFrame:`, and theres this other method `buttonWithType:` which I assume is autoreleased, but anyway I couldn't get a button to appear on the screen. Could someone please write a bit of code that locally creates a button with a title I can change that I can then just add to my views subview and release so I can see how it's done?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

```
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 44); // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
    [myButton setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // add targets and actions
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // add to a view
    [superView addSubview:myButton];
```

Disclaimer: Just typing this in here. I don't have access to my Mac at the moment so I can't test it.

P.S. Any particular reason not to use Interface Builder? Just curious.

Comment: Assuming the selector `buttonClicked:` exists, this is perfectly valid and a good way to go about it. +1

Comment: I don't like IB because its like a big black box and I can't see what's going on and it just complicates things... Only thing I think its useful for is designing the interface.

Is this myButton autoreleased? Would it also works if I did
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:...];
.. but then how would I set the readonly button type..

Comment: And couldn't I do myButton.titleLabel.text = @"Click Me!" instead of setTitle forState?

Comment: The buttonType is a read only property. I'm not sure what type of button you'd get if you initWithFrame:, and you won't be able to change it later. You could try it and see what the buttonType property is, but it's probably safer to go with buttonWithType:.

Yes, this button would be autoreleased.

Not sure about setting myButton.titleLabel.text. If you later want to add different titles for different states I guess you'd have to change the code then. I'd only use myButton.titleLabel for modifying the styling of the button, like color, font and font size.

Comment: And if I do [myButton retain] it will act as a normal object that I am responsible for releasing correct?

Comment: Yes.

If you just want to add it to your view you wouldn't need to retain the button, though. Your superView would do that when you call [superView addSubview:myButton];

Comment: @Mk12, check out this answer to [UIButton alloc initWithFrame:frame vs. UIButton buttonWithType](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245882/uibutton-alloc-initwithframeframe-vs-uibutton-buttonwithtype/6245883#6245883).

Comment: The action selector can optionally be of the form:
   - (void) buttonClicked:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event