# how can i highlight my image view awhen user touching it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tasks with my UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278942/tasks-with-my-uiimageview)

How can i highlight my UIImageview and display a deleteButton(cross button) on top of the imageview when user touching the UIImageview?.

Comment: isn't this essentially the same question you asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6278942/3009)?

Comment: please help me ...basically i am a C# developer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a IBAction that adds the cross button and wire it to the touchDown event in interface builder. You could probably make a timer that will give it a couple seconds before activating.

Option 2: read about gestureRecognizers, they are very simple and I learned them in a couple hours.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html <-- all about recogizers

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward. Use

> UILongPressGestureRecognizer

In the methods below write a code for detecting gestures and popping up a delete button.

```
- (void)handleGesture; //or
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
```

For deleting use

```
- (void)removeTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
```